# Jquery Dialog Limit Height

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery dialog which opens up on button click.

There is a grid view within the jquery dialog.

Sometimes there are a lot of rows within the gridview , in which case the dialog stretches from the top of the
   screen to the bottom.

I would like to limit the size of the dialog and add a scroll bar.

I tried a combination of all the following settings as shown below  but it still doesnt work .

```
 $(function () {
        $("#Div1").dialog({
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true
             autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            MinHeight: '20',
            maxHeight: '400',
            width: '700',
            scroll: true,
            resizable: false,
            create: function () {
                $(this).css("maxHeight", 400);
            }
        });
    });
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

you can retrieve height of object using [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and check it against a variable

```
var maxHeight = 200;
var currentHeight = $('#gridviewContainer').height(); 
var desiredHeight = (currentHeight  < maxHeight ) ? currentHeight : maxHeight;
.dialog({
    height: desiredHeight,
    scrollable: true
});
```

Comment: Hey Dan_vitch ! Thank you ! You have answered my question , but I have another problem. I cannot use height: 200 as some of the elements in the gridview can have just 1 or 2 rows and in that case the popup would show empty space . I used maxHeight : 700 instead of height : 200 and the scrollable feature doesnt work. Do you know of a solution for this. Let me know I can put it up as a new question .

Comment: Hey dan_vitch ! can you just see if you woul know the answer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865797/setting-an-asp-net-label-to-the-title-of-a-jquery-dialog