# setting an asp.net label to the title of a jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I would like to set the jquery dialog title using an asp.net label . Is it possible?

I have tried something like this :

```
 $(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', 'Title Name');
```

But the Title Name here  is static. I would like to use my asp.net label here instead of the 'Title Name'.

I also have my code updated below :

Asp.Net code :

```
 <div id="Div1" class="InsertBar">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="true" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" ScrollBars="Auto">
                                    <asp:GridView>
*******GRIDVIEW CODE ************************
                                     </asp:GridView>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>
```

Java Script Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ViewModelPopup1() {

            $(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', $('#<%=Label2.ClientID%>').val());

        }
    </script>
```

---

**The reason I am using a label here (thought I would mention it):**

I have an asp.net grid view. I am displaying the gridview in a jquery dialog. I have to fetch a value from the
grid view and use it as a title to the jquery dialog.

I am fetching the value from the grid view and storing it in a label.

I would now want to assign the value of the label to the jquery dialog title.

Does anyone know how I can do this ? or have any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text());
```

Note: Change `Label1` to match the name of your ASP.NET Label control.

Comment: Hey Karl Anderson ! Thank you ! But somehow I see that , this doesn't seem to be working for me . I have my code updated in the question

Comment: $(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text());